# Why Today App Extension Widget in SwiftUI is white?

Tags: ios, swift, widget, swiftui, extension-methods

[just like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3PmKU.png)

and my view is simply:

```
Text("Testing Widget")
```

and tried this:

```
VStack {
    Text("Testing Widget")
}
.background(Color(UIColor.clear))
```

and nothing happend:(.

Comment: tried to set the background color to clear?

Comment: yes i tried, nothing happend :(

Comment: how about if you try   .background(Color.white.opacity(0.0001))

Comment: .opacity(0.0001) didn't work too :((((

Comment: provide a bit more code, so we can replicate your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just came across a solution for me!

You have to set the `backgroundColor` of the `UIHostingController`'s `view` to `.clear`, and then it will work. You don't need to set the background color of the SwiftUI view.

```
let hostingController = UIHostingController(rootView: SwiftUIView())

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    view.addSubview(hostingController.view)
    addChild(hostingController)
    hostingController.didMove(toParent: self)

    // You may want to add constraints

    hostingController.view.backgroundColor = .clear // <- IMPORTANT
}
```